# Creating a login from a Windows domain account

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I want to create login for windows domain account. So I tried this code:

```
 CREATE LOGIN [WORKGROUP\arp_admin] FROM WINDOWS;
 GO
```

WORKGROUP is domain name which I have found using `select DEFAULT_DOMAIN()` and arp_login is the login name which I want to assign, but I am getting this error:

> "Windows NT user or group 'WORKGROUP\neutroline_admin' not found.
>   Check the name again."

Help me!

Comment: `CREATE LOGIN` only creates a mapping for existing accounts so that they can access SQL Server. In this case, because you're in a Workgroup as opposed to an Active Directory domain, the `neutroline_admin` has to already exist on the Windows machine hosting SQL Server. Also, you need to use `FOO\neutroline_admin` where `FOO` is the actual name of the machine hosting SQL Server.

Comment: Although you can create a login for a local windows account when the SQL machine is not part of a domain, you won't be able to authenticate remotely using that account without jumping through hoops. Consider SQL authentication for workgroup servers.

Comment: Where "jumping through hoops" is creating an account with a matching name and password on any other workgroup servers you want to authenticate to/from, and keeping those passwords in-sync.